# Getting the user id for a given token

Tags: box-api

I'm using box API v2 and successfully with OAuth2. I'm successfully getting the access token back, but in order to avoid the "confused deputy problem" I need to have a way of getting the user id that a given access token relates to.

Is there a way of doing this? I'm trying to use the /tokens endpoint without luck. I read that you need to enable that but I can't find how. Even if I managed to enable it, would that help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `/users/me` endpoint will tell you the user id (and other info) associated with the access token that was used to authenticate the request. [Documentation here.](http://developers.box.com/docs/#users-get-the-current-users-information-2)

Comment: Anyway, it'd be cool if the user info would be returned alongisde the acces token. In that way, this second call can be avoided.